# В чём ошибка? Почему не работает?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DoIKnow {
    int[] location;
    int win = 0;

    void setLocation(int[] myArray) {
        location = myArray;
    }

    String getInput(String promt) {
        String inputLine = null;
        System.out.print(promt + " ");
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = is.readLine();
            if(inputLine.length() == 0) 
                return null;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOExpetion: " + e); 
        }
        return inputLine;
    }

    String check(String guess) {
        String result = "Мимо";
        int number = Integer.parseInt(guess);
        if(location[number] ==  1) {
            result = "Попал";
            win++;
            location[number] -= 1;
        }
        if(win == 3) {
            result = "Потопил";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numOfGuesses = 0;
        String result;
        DoIKnow game = new DoIKnow();
        int rand = (int) (Math.random()*5);
        int[] arr = new int[7];
        for(int s = 0; s < 3; s++) {
            // цикл для того, чтобы присвоить индексу[rand] 
            // и двум индексам перед ним значение 1
            arr[rand+s] = 1;
        } 
        game.setLocation(arr);
        while(true) {
            result = game.getInput("Введите число");
            result = game.check(result);
            numOfGuesses++;
            if(result.equals("Потопил")) {
                System.out.println("Вам потребовалось " + numOfGuesses + "попыток(и)");
                break;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Ожидаемый результат (примерно):

> Пользователь вводит число, если он угадывает (индекс, хранящий
>   значение 1), то возвращает "Попал", если возвращается "Потопил", то
>   код выходит из цикла и показывается, сколько попыток понадобилось

Comment: Могу добавить комментарии, если требуется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я исправил программу. Полный исходник ты можешь найти в конце ответа
Во первых пише чише, более красиво( https://habr.com/ru/post/112042/ )
Что я исправил?

1)Проверку на ноль

```
 do
 {
 result = game.getInput("Введите число");
 }
 while(result == null || result.isEmpty());
```

2)Программа не обрабала цифры больше 7.

```
do
{
inputLine = is.readLine();


if(inputLine.length() == 0) return null;

if(Integer.parseInt(inputLine)>=7)
{
    System.out.println("Привет, я программа. Нужно ввести меньше цыфры семь, \nпотому что цыфры больше 7 я не умею обрабатывать,\n так как в меня не добавили такой функционал\n ");    
    System.out.println("Введите число: ");
}



}
while(Integer.parseInt(inputLine)>=7);
```

3) Добавить проверку на ввод, что ввели именно цифры,а не строку.

4) Формулируй более четко вопрос, что именно неправильно выполняется в коде.

Добавляю как html код, т.к. не могу добавить как Java code
Исправленый код:

```html
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

 int[] location;
 int win = 0;

 void setLocation(int[] myArray) {
  this.location = myArray;
 }

 String getInput(String promt) throws java.io.IOException {
  String inputLine = null;

  boolean input_right = true;
  BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  do {
   System.out.print(promt + " ");
   inputLine = is.readLine();
   input_right = check_input_for_match_of_format_if_all_okey_return_false(inputLine);
  } while (input_right);

  return inputLine;
 }

 private boolean check_input_for_match_of_format_if_all_okey_return_false(String inputLine) {

  if (inputLine.replaceAll(" ", "").length() == 0) {
   System.out.println("You can't input empty space");
   return true;
  }

  // check for letters
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

  if (matcher.matches()) {
   System.out.println("You can't input letters");
   return true;
  }
  // ...

  if (Integer.parseInt(inputLine) >= 7) {
   System.out.println("You can't input numbers more than 6");
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }

 String check(String guess) {

  String result = "Мимо";
  int number = Integer.parseInt(guess);

  if (location[number] == 1) {
   result = "Попал";
   win++;
   location[number] -= 1;
  }

  if (win == 3) {
   result = "Потопил";
  }

  return result;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
  Main main = new Main();
  main.start();
 }

 public void start() throws IOException {
  // initialize variables
  int numOfGuesses = 0;
  String result;
  int[] arr = generate_new_array();
  // ...

  Main game = new Main();
  game.setLocation(arr);

  while (true) {
   result = game.getInput("Введите число");
   result = game.check(result);
   numOfGuesses++;

   if (result.equals("Потопил")) {
    System.out.println("Вам потребовалось " + numOfGuesses + "попыток(и)");
    break;
   }
  }
 }// end method

 private int[] generate_new_array() {

  int[] arr = new int[7];
  int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

  for (int s = 0; s < 3; s++) {
   arr[rand + s] = 1;
  }

  return arr;
 }

}
```

Comment: `Во первых пише чише, более красиво` после такого ожидал в `Исправленый код:` красивое форматирование кода, а не это :)

Comment: Если ввести пробел, то сразу ляжет с NumberFormatException, если ввести отрицательное число, то ляжет с IndexOutOfBounds. И это только первый метод

Comment: То есть у меня не работал код по причине того, что у меня не было проверок на ввод?

Comment: Я исправил код, сделал его более чистым. Ошибки которые указаны выше в коментарии появляются из-за того, что нету проверки, я добавил пару из проверок в метод check_input_for_match_of_format_if_all_okey_return_false(). Да код не работал по той причине, что не было проверок на ввод. Я бы рекомендовал сайт codewars для начинающих, очень хороший сайт.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!